# How to get the differences between two rows **and** the name of the field where the difference is, in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in **BigQuery** like this:

| Name | Phone Number | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 123456778564 | 1 Penny Lane |
| John | 873452987424 | 1 Penny Lane |
| Mary | 845704562848 | 87 5th Avenue |
| Mary | 845704562848 | 54 Lincoln Rd. |
| Amy | 342847327234 | 4 Ocean Drive Avenue |
| Amy | 347907387469 | 98 Truman Rd. |

I want to get a table with the differences between two consecutive rows and the name of the field where occurs the difference:

I mean this:

| Name | Field | Before | After |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Phone Number | 123456778564 | 873452987424 |
| Mary | Address | 87 5th Avenue | 54 Lincoln Rd. |
| Amy | Phone Number | 342847327234 | 347907387469 |
| Amy | Address | 4 Ocean Drive Avenue | 98 Truman Rd. |

How can I do this ? I've looked on other posts but couldn't find something that corresponds to my need.

Thank you

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "before" and "after" unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: Let's say I have a timestamp field also @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below BigQuery'ish solution

```
select Name, ['Phone Number', 'Address'][offset(offset)] Field, 
  prev_field as Before, field as After
from (
  select timestamp, Name, offset, field,
    lag(field) over (partition by Name, offset order by timestamp) as prev_field
  from yourtable,
  unnest([`Phone Number`, Address]) field with offset
)
where prev_field != field
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

As you can see here - no matter how many columns in your table that you need to compare - it is still just one query - no unions and such.
You just need to enumerate your columns in two places

```
['Phone Number', 'Address'][offset(offset)] Field
```

and

```
unnest([`Phone Number`, Address]) field with offset
```

Note: you can further refactor above using scripting's `execute immediate` to compose such lists within the query on the fly (check my other answers - I frequently use such technique in them)

Comment: Thank you very much ! This works perfectly fine ! But do you know how can I get the name of all the columns in my table instead of writing each one of them ? I tried to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS but it didn't work. @MikhailBerlyant

Comment: see the last sentence in my answer :o)

Answer (score 2):

One method is just use to use `lag()` and `union all`

```
select name, 'phone', prev_phone as before, phone as after
from (select name, phone,
             lag(phone) over (partition by name order by timestamp) as prev_phone
      from t
     ) t
where prev_phone <> phone
union all
select name, 'address', prev_address as before, address as afte4r
from (select name, address,
             lag(address) over (partition by name order by timestamp) as prev_address
      from t
     ) t
where prev_address <> address
```